# Cannot store image as binary in mysql django and also check the size of the image in forms.py

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am creating a website in django. I need to store the image as binary in mysql database as well as check its size before saving. Tried many ways nothing seems to help.

views.py

```
def client_create_view(request):
       base_form = ClientForm(None, initial=initial_data)
       context={ "form": base_form }

       if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ClientForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

         if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

       return render(request,'cc.html',context)
```

forms.py

```
class ClientForm(ModelForm):
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        super(ClientForm, self).clean()
        photo_image = self.cleaned_data['photo'].file.read()
        if photo_image.file_size > 0.250:
             raise ValidationError(['Image Size should be lower than 250kb'])
```

html

```
<form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
#some data
</form>
```

Comment: use [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads)

Comment: @MojtabaKamyabi  I am using Image Field

Comment: You already asked this question before.

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby Both the Questions are different

Comment: You can't save with the form you have to do things manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle things manually, you can't use `form.save()`

```
def client_create_view(request):
    base_form = ClientForm(None, initial=initial_data)
    context = { "form": base_form }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.image = request.FILES["image_file"].read()
            form.instance.save()
    return render(request,'cc.html',context)
```